# making image opaq if id is A make image not opaq if id is B

Tags: jquery, image

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var $message = $('div.utilul3 .moveThis img');
$message.filter('[id="i_icon_mini_message"]')
   .find('.utilities img').addClass('opaqimg');
$message.filter('[id="i_icon_mini_new_message"]')
   .find('.utilities img').removeClass('opaqimg');
});​
```

What I am trying to do is the `id` equals `i_icon_mini_message` then make the image in `.utilities` opaque which I addClass `.opaqimg`

If the `id` equals `i_icon_mini_new_message` then make the image not opaque by doing nothing, though I create fix just to ensure by doing a `.removeClass`

The code above though seems to be not working for me. I also tried instead of doing

`.filter('[id="i_icon_mini_message]')` by doing `.attr('id','i_icon_mini_message')` that seemed to throw a console error by not reading the correct values.

Can someone help me achieve what I am trying to accomplish here

http://jsfiddle.net/3tG2x/1/   search for id name

http://jsfiddle.net/3tG2x/2/   search for title

Comment: What is not working? Also, the CSS ID selector starts with a `#` like in `filter( '#i_icon_mini_message' )` to select an element via it's ID. Why do you need JavaScript at all? Can't you just add those opaque definitions to the stylesheet declarations for those ID's?

Comment: What is the point of filtering when you can just include that in the original selector?

Comment: @feeela it's because the ID is changed via PHP

Comment: But you are effectively selecting an ID?

Comment: yeah, well not selecting searching if that id exist then change the other element image. I'll fix the markup just realized it is wrong

Comment: nevermind it is not wrong. The smilie is what i am going to try to change (not really for my site) just a test. The img is a blank image really that we are checking the id on

Comment: I could also filter it by title, for atleast adding the class `('[title="You have no new messages"]')` though that does not seem to work either

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be invoking `find` on a collection of `img` elements. This will never work, since `img` elements have no descendants.

To add the opaque class to all images with the id `i_icon_mini_message`, use:

```
$('img#i_icon_mini_message').addClass('opaqimg');
```

Similarly, to remove the class:

```
$('img#i_icon_mini_new_message').removeClass('opaqimg');
```